# Is there a way to only run i18n-tasks normalize on certain files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n, i18n-tasks

We have `i18n-tasks normalize` running as part of a husky git commit hook but since we have added other locales it is now extremely slow to run.

Is it possible to pass file paths to `i18n-tasks normalize` so that only locale files that have changed are normalized?

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of research and checked [source code](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks/blob/881ed6f3d2aed94fa0aae050584f9cddc11536d7/lib/i18n/tasks/command/commands/data.rb#L20)

```rb
 def normalize(opt = {})
   i18n.normalize_store! locales: opt[:locales],
                         force_pattern_router: opt[:pattern_router]
end
```

So something like that should work.
`i18n-tasks normalize --locales en`
Or try with single dash